# ZFS pool not mounting correctly; can't find all files

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a ZFS pool (mirrored RAID) on two disks that I've transferred from a FreeBSD 11.0 server into an Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS server.

After importing the pool, I see:

```
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zroot                993G   790G   104K  /mnt/zfs
zroot/ROOT           989G   790G    96K  none
zroot/ROOT/default   989G   790G   989G  none
zroot/tmp            140K   790G   140K  none
zroot/usr           3.37G   790G    96K  none
zroot/usr/home      2.15G   790G  2.15G  none
zroot/usr/ports      640M   790G   640M  none
zroot/usr/src        608M   790G   608M  none
zroot/var           1.66M   790G    96K  none
zroot/var/audit       96K   790G    96K  none
zroot/var/crash       96K   790G    96K  none
zroot/var/log        476K   790G   476K  none
zroot/var/mail       840K   790G   840K  none
zroot/var/tmp         96K   790G    96K  none
```

What I expect to see is a fully-populated directory tree under `/mnt/zfs` on the Ubuntu system, containing 993GiB of files.  What I see instead is a partially-populated tree of directories, with no files inside them:

```
$ tree /mnt/zfs
/mnt/zfs
├── tmp
├── usr
│   ├── home
│   ├── ports
│   └── src
└── var
    ├── audit
    ├── crash
    ├── log
    ├── mail
    └── tmp
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fundamental here.

*Attempt #1:* Setting a mountpoint for ROOT, as per @Zoredache's suggestion, just results in an empty ROOT directory:

```
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/zfs/ROOT zroot/ROOT
$ tree /mnt/zfs
/mnt/zfs
└── ROOT
```

*Attempt #2:* Setting a mountpoint for ROOT/default, as per @user121391's suggestion, also yields an empty directory:

```
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/zfs/ROOT zroot/ROOT/default
$ tree /mnt/zfs
/mnt/zfs

0 directories, 0 files
```

*Attempt #3:* Mounting an individual directory seems to work, as per @user131391's other suggestion:

```
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/zfs/usr/home zroot/usr/home
$ tree /mnt/zfs
/mnt/zfs
└── usr
    └── home
        └── duncan
            ├── tmp
            │   ├── code
...
            └── usb

17978 directories, 67539 files
```

Which is great, but unfortunately that's no help.  The files I'm after are under `/usr/local/`, which doesn't appear in the result of `zfs list`.  The space is clearly being used, though, if you look at the sizes:

```
zroot/ROOT/default   989G   790G   989G  none
zroot/usr           3.37G   790G    96K  none
```

*Attempt #4:*

Further information for Michael Kjörling:

```
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/zfs/ROOT zroot/ROOT/default
$ sudo zfs get mountpoint,mounted zroot -t filesystem -r
NAME                PROPERTY    VALUE          SOURCE
zroot               mountpoint  none           local
zroot               mounted     no             -
zroot/ROOT          mountpoint  none           local
zroot/ROOT          mounted     no             -
zroot/ROOT/default  mountpoint  /mnt/zfs/ROOT  local
zroot/ROOT/default  mounted     no             -
zroot/tmp           mountpoint  none           local
zroot/tmp           mounted     no             -
zroot/usr           mountpoint  none           local
zroot/usr           mounted     no             -
zroot/usr/home      mountpoint  none           local
zroot/usr/home      mounted     no             -
zroot/usr/ports     mountpoint  none           local
zroot/usr/ports     mounted     no             -
zroot/usr/src       mountpoint  none           local
zroot/usr/src       mounted     no             -
zroot/var           mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var           mounted     no             -
zroot/var/audit     mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var/audit     mounted     no             -
zroot/var/crash     mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var/crash     mounted     no             -
zroot/var/log       mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var/log       mounted     no             -
zroot/var/mail      mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var/mail      mounted     no             -
zroot/var/tmp       mountpoint  none           local
zroot/var/tmp       mounted     no             -
$ tree /mnt/zfs
/mnt/zfs

0 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Just setting the mountpoint doesn't actually mount the file system. Can we see `zfs get mountpoint,mounted zroot -t filesystem -r`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've added that information to the question, above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zroot and zroot/ROOT don't contain any files, they are just containers for the other data.

The bulk of your data is in zroot/ROOT/default.

The other zfs filesystems should inherit their mountpoint from zroot (not sure how this information got lost in the transition from FreeBSD to Ubuntu):

```
zfs inherit mountpoint zroot/tmp
zfs inherit mountpoint zroot/usr
zfs inherit mountpoint zroot/usr/home
zfs inherit mountpoint zroot/usr/ports
```

... and so on (it may be possible to do a -r on this but I haven't checked).

The only zfs filesystem which should have a mountpoint of `none` is zroot/ROOT:

```
zfs set mountpoint=none zroot/ROOT
```

After doing all this, you'll need to export and re-import the pool, and mount the filesystems in the correct order:

```
zpool export zroot
```

Import the pool to the new mountpoint but don't actually mount anything:

```
zpool import -a -N -r /mnt/zfs
```

Mount the root pool:

```
zfs mount zroot/ROOT/default
```

Mount everything else:

```
zfs mount -a
```

Comment: `zpool import -a -N -R /mnt/zfs` worked for me, on FreeBSD (uppercase -R)

Answer (score 2):

Check the `MOUNTPOINT` column. It looks like there are no mountpoints for anything.  You might want to try setting mountpoints for your datasets.

For example I believe this would mount `zroot/ROOT` to `/mnt/zfs/ROOT`.

```
zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/zfs/ROOT zroot/ROOT
```

I don't know enough about ZFS to tell you why this wouldn't happen automatically, or if it should when importing onto a Linux system.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but setting the ROOT mountpoint just causes an empty directory to be created (see edits to question for details).

Comment: @DuncanBayne Have you tried mounting anything else? I think the ROOT should not contain anything by itself, but `zroot/ROOT/default` should.

Comment: @user121391 I tried default, but that didn't work.  Mounting individual elements in the result from zfs list seems to work, but doesn't give me access to the bulk of the 989GiB of files :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to zfs set a mountpoint for the root of the zpool, and `zfs inherit -r mountpoint <zpool name>` to recursively set the mountpoint. After which `zfs mount -a` mounts all the datasets.